# What is the conventional architecture for a Rails 5 API with an Administrative UI as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, devops, rails-api

I was setting out to start a new Rails 5 API, and realized I also need a content-administration "site" of some sort. The admin tool is very simple, just a UI for very basic CRUD operations.

I have an instinct to create two separate Rails applications - one web application for the content-admin tool, and another web application for the API.

This brings about the problem with sharing data models, which is solvable by using rails engines, or including the models as a gem.

As I was researching solutions, I seemed to observe a pattern of including the content-admin portion within the API app itself. There are some middleware includes and controller inheritances involved in this, but its quite simple to get a content-admin UI to run within the same app as an API. Its much less work, and I dont see much of a problem with scale, since the content-admin UI is lightly utilized and the API is the core of the business.

Is this the accepted convention? I might be gaining a bias due to web search results, but it seems like the simplest and most common approach. I plan to have a separate server for accessing the content-admin vs accessing the API, which is what led me to originally plan this as two separate apps. Now I am thinking I was just getting sucked into the "microservices" hype, and it seems more conventional to just include the content-admin UI with my API app.

On the other side, everything I read about Rails engines is 3-4 years out of date. There is little information (that I am stumbling upon) within the last year or so, and more specifically, little-to-no information concerning Rails 5. I am wondering if this sort of architecture has fallen by the wayside.

Is there a typical convention for Rails 5 API applications that also need a content-admin UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I've used before is to have the api running out of `/app/controllers/api` and then have the [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) gem installed, with the admin interface files in `/app/admin`. You can set up the routes to serve the admin interface at `https://api.yourapp.com/admin` and the API at `https://api.yourapp.com/api/v1/` or similar.

I don't know how much of an accepted convention this is, but it works fine.

Comment: Yah, this is generally what it appears to be, and as Ive researched engine/component based solutions, Ive come to know `ActiveAdmin` as essentially an engine already.